# How do I allow my users to customize their dashboards in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm confused on a basic concept. I'm working on a LAMP project where vendors submit products to companies for review. Each company has their own dedicated form that the vendors can access from their dashboard to submit products for review to the companies. Then the companies have their dashboard where they can review these products.

My question is how do I program for the companies to have the ability to switch the questions they want to ask of the vendors? So upon setting up their account I create a form for the companies that include ten questions of their choosing. Obviously there is a way with PHP for the companies to access these ten questions from their dashboard and to swap these questions out for others that will then populate on their forms that show up on the vendors dashboard. Since it affects my database code and my form code I'm confused on how to handle this and I haven't been able to come up with the right search terms for here or google that will show me resources on how to do this. What is the basic concept here? Am I writing code to literally overwrite the php source code for the companies forms page? Or is the database somehow involved with a global list of questions that are chosen? I am sure this is a basic function of php but I have never dealt with it so a "Mr. Potato Head" explanation and a link to a resource from the community would be real helpful.

EDITED:
I may have been asking this question wrong above. This is far more a php question than a MySQL question. I don't understand the concept of customized forms. If a company chooses to swap out one of their questions and I give them a page where they can adjust their questions, what happens after they hit submit and have selected a new set of questions? Do I set the PHP up to completely overwrite the source code of their form page? That doesn't seem right so I am looking for examples of customized forms....

Comment: 'Do I set the PHP up to completely overwrite the source code of their form page?' Well, I guess you should dig into PHP some more, because the PHP should make the form. So you don't _overwrite_ the source code, you _make_ it - on the fly. Get your database data (the right questions for the right company) and let PHP cobble together the form. There are good examples, for sure, but like you I can't seem to find one as quickly on Google. I remember some PHP books that take you through this kind of stuff step by step, though...

Comment: Okay kasimir, just based on your response its already becoming more clear. So my ENTIRE form.php page is written in PHP, nothing static including my database code? Then I just swap out variables based on options chosen which are sitting in the database. Is this the basic concept? So I am looking for forms examples written entirely in PHP with user customizable options correct? Thanks for the insight so far. I know this is totally elementary, not sure why it is throwing me for a loop...

Comment: Yup, that's about right. What you do with PHP is 1. Generate the form (with questions based on what's in the db), 2. Form validation (to see if no required fields remain empty), 3. Process results/answers (store in your db and echo back for the user to review). This example runs you through these basics: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-processing.html. The hard part for you is to customize this basic example to fit your goals. But this problem solving is what makes programming rewarding.

Answer (score 0):

How about you have a table of Questions with lots of possible questions
Then you have a table of Company_Questions which is just a subset of those questions, chosen by the company. You may then add a question to Questions or just create/swap an entry in Company_Questions to the selected Question.

I think you should look at some Data(base) Design books first, because you may be missing some  key concepts.

Comment: Thanks yogurt. So my MySQL skills are far stronger than my PHP skills. I understand that a company can select from a global list of questions and I can move the tables around to reflect their choices. My question is then what...? What should my code be doing? Completely swapping out parts of the source code? Because the companies choices will affect not only the html displayed for the form but also the PHP INSERT statements for the form. I don't want to recreate the wheel and I am sure this is a common feature so Im looking for examples of current usage for something like this. Thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like this in your database schema:

users(id, name, other params);
questions(id, question);

You need to do a 1:N relationship to save for all customers the questions their want.

user_que(id_user,id_question, order);

Note: the param 'order' is just to specify the order the client want the question, and to clarify you can add more columns if you want to that table.

Well with that you can do the job. Now some SQL

**Get the questions from a client**
    SELECT q.question FROM questions q, user_que uq WHERE uq.id_user = $client_id

***Get the clients who have one question***
    SELECT c.name FROM users c, user_que uq WHERE uq.id_question = $id_question

Hope it helps you.